# configuring Apache on Mountain Lion proxying to Node.js

Tags: apache, node.js, osx-mountain-lion, mod-proxy

I'm trying to get Apache on OSX 10.8.2 to proxy requests to a specific URL to a Node.js server running on port 8080 following this guide: http://garrows.com/?p=455
In order to do this, I add the following to apache2/users/george.conf:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /foo http://localhost:8080
ProxyPassReverse /foo http://localhost:8080
```

But with this added, apache wont start.
In fact, as soon as I add even the 'ProxyRequests Off' directive, apache will no longer start.
Is this the right place for this directive?

Comment: anything in the apache log?  likely to be under /private/var/log/apache2

Comment: there's no indication of what went wrong in file private/var/log/apache2/error_log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me (I use port 3000 to connect to my own server here):

```
<Directory "/Users/psq/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /foo http://localhost:3000
ProxyPassReverse /foo http://localhost:3000
```

But does not work if you place it inside `<Directory>`.

To debug, you can run:

```
sudo apachectl configtest
```

This will tell you where there is an error in your config.

Comment: typo  sudo apachectl configtest